# Issue using 3D Touch Quick Action

Tags: ios, swift

So I am using quick action in my application, but I am having a issue.
[image]

At you can see, when the app opens the "Welcome" view controller, and after one second it opens the first tab bar item. I have three quick action actions:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

        let rootNavigationController = window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        let tabbarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController

        rootNavigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

        if shortcutItem.type == "FEED" {
            print("Shortcut item tapped: FEED")
            // go to FEED view controller
            tabbarController!.selectedViewController = tabbarController!.viewControllers?[0]
        }
        if shortcutItem.type == "EXPLORE" {
            print("Shortcut item tapped: EXPLORE")
            // go to EXPLORE view controller
            tabbarController!.selectedViewController = tabbarController!.viewControllers?[1]
        }
        if shortcutItem.type == "UPLOAD" {
            print("Shortcut item tapped: UPLOAD")
            // go to UPLOAD view controller
            tabbarController!.selectedViewController = tabbarController!.viewControllers?[2]
        }
    }
```

My app crashes in the `tabbarController!.selectedViewController` code. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because  tabbarcontroller is nill

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk - How come? It does exist, because i have it.. How should i do it?